# Using Regular Expression To Match Strings In PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm a beginner, and am having problems with a regular expression which I have found to work using the RegExr tool.

I'm loading a set of titles of classified ads from an XML file called properties.xml which I am showing here -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title>For Sale - Toaster Oven</title>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>For Sale - Sharp Scissors</title>
    </item>
<item>
      <title>For Sale - Book Ends</title>
    </item>
<item>
      <title>For Sale - Mouse Trap</title>
    </item>
<item>
      <title>For Sale - Water Dispenser</title>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Here's the PHP code which parses the XML and then checks if there are matches; unfortunately it shows none.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("properties.xml");

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
    $title = $item->title;
    $myregex = preg_quote("/(?<=For(.)Sale(.)-(.))[^]+/");
    $result = preg_match($myregex, $title, $trim_title);
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

I've checked the regular expression against the RegExr tool, and it seems fine - here's a screencap

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your regular expression with the `[^]`. The caret is used to negate the matching characters in square brackets. For example `[^a]` won't match an a.

Your regex isn't ideal to be honest. If all you want to match is whatever comes after the "For Sale" string I'd just use

> /For Sale - ([^<]+)/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either - the entire string is selected instead of whatever that comes after the "For Sale - " string as desired. Here's a screencap from RegExr - http://i.imgur.com/ygszr.png

Comment: Forget what is or isn't matching in RegExr — PHP will only give you what you ask for with capturing groups (i.e. the brackets). As @Maks3w points out you'll probably need to access the `text()` of the node instead of the node itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Xpath to query the XML file

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("properties.xml");
$results = $xml->xpath('//title/text()');

static $myregex = '/For Sale - (.*)/';
while(list( , $title) = each($results)) {
    $result = preg_match($myregex, $title, $trim_title);
    $trim_title = $trim_title[1];
    echo $result; // Number of matches
    echo $trim_title;
}
```

more simple is

```
while(list( , $title) = each($results)) {
    echo substr($title, 11) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the old code is not accessing to the text() of the XML element

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried running this but echo $result still returns a bunch of 0's unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("properties.xml");

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
    preg_match("/For Sale(.*)<\/title>/siU", $item);
    echo trim($item[1]," -");
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't to need deal with the closing tags, SimpleXML gives you enough methods to access to the text